# How to correctly setup home directories and permissions on a mounted partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions, fedora, samba

I'm setting up a Fedora 12 server. I have a root (/) partition where the boot (/boot) partition is mounted and then a separate partition (/files) for separating home directories and shares away from the other partitions.

The filesystem mounts fine and users can be created to have home directories in /files/home/[user] just fine. However, when I log in (or ssh in) as one of those users, I get an error saying "Cannot chdir in to /files/home/[user]: permission denied". However, once logged in, I can "cd /files/home/[user]" just fine. If I create a user under the default /home using the same process, everything works as expected.

The same goes for when I try and browse a share in windows; I can see the shares, but cannot access them.

The permissions and owners on /files and /files/home are the same as /home. When the user is created, the user directory owner and permissions are also the same.

How can I set the /files partition up so that it can be used as a home directory and for samba sharing rather than using the root (/) partition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned off selinux.